How I should create metadata with Metaplex Token Data in ReactJS and the correctly use to createMetadataAccountV3?
Im trying to send metadata with Metaplex to one transaction in Solana, but this is not possible, always get one error:
error TypeError: context.programs.getPublicKey is not a function at Object.createMetadataAccountV3 (createMetadataAccountV3.ts:111:38) 
Image Error
This is my code:
[....]
const contextMetaData = {
            eddsa: signTransaction,
            identity: publicKey,
            payer: publicKey,
            programs: {
              tokenMetadata: new PublicKey("AddressProgram"), 
            },
          };

const metadataAccount = await mpl.createMetadataAccountV3(contextMetaData, {
  metadata: undefined, // empty
  mint: mint.PublicKey, 
  mintAuthority: publicKey, 
  payer: publicKey,
  updateAuthority: 
  data: {
    name,
    symbol,
    uri: uri,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0, 
    creators: null, 
  },
  isMutable: true, 
  collectionDetails: null, 
});

This is the instruction:
/**
 * This code was AUTOGENERATED using the kinobi library.
 * Please DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, instead use visitors
 * to add features, then rerun kinobi to update it.
 *
 * @see https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/kinobi
 */
import { Context, Option, OptionOrNullable, Pda, PublicKey, Signer, TransactionBuilder } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';
import { Serializer } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi/serializers';
import { CollectionDetails, CollectionDetailsArgs, DataV2, DataV2Args } from '../types';
export type CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
    /** Metadata key (pda of ['metadata', program id, mint id]) */
    metadata?: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Mint of token asset */
    mint: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Mint authority */
    mintAuthority: Signer;
    /** payer */
    payer?: Signer;
    /** update authority info */
    updateAuthority?: PublicKey | Pda | Signer;
    /** System program */
    systemProgram?: PublicKey | Pda;
    /** Rent info */
    rent?: PublicKey | Pda;
};
export type CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionData = {
    discriminator: number;
    data: DataV2;
    isMutable: boolean;
    collectionDetails: Option<CollectionDetails>;
};
export type CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs = {
    data: DataV2Args;
    isMutable: boolean;
    collectionDetails: OptionOrNullable<CollectionDetailsArgs>;
};
export declare function getCreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataSerializer(): Serializer<CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionData>;
export type CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs = CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs;
export declare function createMetadataAccountV3(context: Pick<Context, 'eddsa' | 'identity' | 'payer' | 'programs'>, input: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts & CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs): TransactionBuilder;


I already check the documentation, but im not expert in this area.  How I should create the correctly instruction to error?
Regards !
I want find the problem or some guide to fix and use correctly createMetadataAccountV3
